# How do I call a Yes / No / Cancel dialog in Pharo 4.0?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

This question is related to [How do I ask the user for a file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198476/how-do-i-ask-the-user-for-a-file-name)

The issue of 'Standard dialogs'.

How do I call a Yes / No / Cancel dialog and how to I call an alert in Pharo 4.0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
UIManager default question: 'foo' title: 'bar'.
```

which answers `true` for Yes, `false` for No, and `nil` for Cancel.

Similarly, an alert can be shown like this:

```
UIManager default alert: 'Hello World'.
```